# Counting multiple rows in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm currently having a table filled with likes and tweets of a certain post sorted on date.

I want to know the query to count the total of likes and tweets sorted by post_id. The result of the example below should be 50 likes and 20 tweets.

The structure of the table is:

```
post_id date    likes   tweets
1   2012-06-09  20  10
1   2012-06-10  30  10
```

Comment: Review the [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) This is a rudimentary `SUM(likes), SUM(tweets)` `GROUP BY post_id`

Comment: What is your table structure and what have you tried so far?

Comment: vote answers and choose best answer if it was working 4u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look [at this doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).
Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(`likes`) AS `likes`, SUM(`tweets`) AS `tweets` FROM `table` GROUP BY `post_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your case:**

your table name assumed: tweets

```
select SUM(likes), SUM(tweet) from post_table group by(post_id)
```

**General Form:**

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
```

Comment: He wanted the sum of both likes and tweets, this is just summing likes